# jQuery: how to find username input field?

Tags: jquery, input, passwords

i tried

```js
var input = $('input:password');
if(input.length>0){
    var form = input[0].closest("form");
    console.log($('#'+form.id).find('*').filter(':input:visible:first'));
  }
```

but it does not find die user input field

i would like to write a chrome extension that prefills username and password in login form.

with `var input = $('input:password');` i'm already able to find the password input. but i need to find a way to find the username input field (1st visible before password)

Is there a way go get username-input and password-input?

Comment: You have to add form html code, so that we can help you properly

Comment: @AlivetoDie I dont think he can, its a Chrome extension so we want to find the input from any html.

Comment: Yes i would like to find it on any website

Comment: Your code just works (username and password fields are logged in console): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jooZQJ

Comment: @yaya pro it depends on the website. Example: www.dkb.de/banking does not work, i get a button as result for user-input -> i have no idea why :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, but it's no guaranty that it will work.

```
var password = $('input:password');
if (password.length > 0) {
  var inputs = $("input");
  var ind = inputs.index(password);
  var username = inputs.eq(ind - 1);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var password = $('input:password');
if (password.length > 0) {
  var inputs = $("input");
  var ind = inputs.index(password);
  var username = inputs.eq(ind - 1);
  console.log(username)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" /></div>
<input type="password">
```

Comment: this one looks great thanks. Now i got a problem with websites that contain login in a modal, but i will open another question for that. thank you!

Comment: @JarITZ No problem.

Comment: @JarITZ note that it won't work if form was formed like: "username - email - password"

Comment: @yayapro maybe not, but for the current requirements for the OP's question it does solve what he asked for, If he need it to look for some more complex stuff, he can make it look for think like `placeholder="username"`

Comment: @yayapro There will most likely always be scenarios where, whatever code he uses don't work. Like if i remove the label username from your codepen it cant find the input.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen if you remove the username label, it will check the placeholder. if placeholder not provided, it will consider the first text input as username. i can change the last part to "the input just before username" as your algorithm do, but i think first input is more likely to be username.

Comment: @yayapro Point is that my answer does what the OP asked If you want to point out scenarios where an answer does not work, then you can basic do it for all answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sorry if i disturbed you. i just commented to questioner in comments before answering, and he answered : "yes, my code works, but it doesnt work on some websites.". and i thought he need a more somplex algorithm, that's why i notified him in this comment that your solution uses a simple algorithm. I didn't want to say your answer is bad or something. sorry anyway.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen and plus i thought "1st visible before password" means first visible input on the form that is before password, not input before password. i think i got it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

way 1. Simple Algorithm : first visible input field of form is Username

fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jooZQJ

```
var input = $('input:password');
console.log(input[0]);
if(input.length>0){
    var form = input[0].closest("form");
    console.log($(form).find('*').filter('input:visible:first')[0]);
  }
```

way 2. complex algorithm : check placeHolder, label and value of input for include word : "username" (case insensitive). and if there isn't such input, do way 1.

the tricky part is also get label of an input. this algorithm check if label is binded to input by "for" attribute equal to input's id , or its just it's before input element.

fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RmmJwG

```
var input = $('input:password');
console.log(input[0]);
if(input.length>0){
    var form = input[0].closest("form");
    var canditates = $(form).find('input:visible');
    var found = null;
    for(var i =0; i<canditates.length; i++){
      var labelTag = getLabel(canditates[i]);
      if(($(canditates[i]).attr('placeholder')
          && $(canditates[i]).attr('placeholder').toLowerCase().indexOf('username') >= 0)
         || $(labelTag).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('username') >= 0
         || $(canditates[i]).val().toLowerCase().indexOf('username') >=0 ){        
        found = canditates[i];
        break;
      };
    }
    var username = found ? found : canditates[0];
    console.log(username);
  }
function getLabel(input){
  var label = $('label[for="' + $(input).attr('id') + '"]');
  if(label.length <= 0) {
    var parentElem = $(input).parent();
    if(parentElem.length == 0)return;
    var parentTagName = parentElem.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase();
    if(parentTagName == "label") {
        label = parentElem;
    }
  }
  if(label.length == 0){
    label = $(input).prev().filter('label');
    label = label.attr('for') ? undefined : label;
  }
  if(label && label.length > 0)return label[0];
  else return null;
}
```